# Copy last value to other cells till we see a filled cell

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list like below :

```
2016-10-05 00:00:00.000
NULL
NULL
NULL
2016-08-12 07:46:00.000
NULL
NULL
```

Which I need to convert to

```
2016-10-05 00:00:00.000
 2016-10-05 00:00:00.000
 2016-10-05 00:00:00.000
 2016-10-05 00:00:00.000
2016-08-12 07:46:00.000
 2016-08-12 07:46:00.000
 2016-08-12 07:46:00.000
```

Basically, I need to capture the last occurrence date and copy it to next rows till i see a filled row.

Here is how I see it working now

```
foreach (var date in dates)
{
    var lastValue = null;

    if(date != null)
    {
        lastValue = date;
    }
    if(date == null)
    {
        date = lastValue;
    }
    else
    {
        lastValue = date;
    }
}
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: show us your effort, please

Comment: I can do it by a manual foreach loop, to see empty value and fill it to next cell if it does not have any value. and refresh the value if it finds one. 

But need to see if there is an efficient way to do it.

Comment: Would be great if you edited your post and show your effort, so that we will know what you have tried.

Comment: what will you do if the first entries are `null`? how is this supposed to be filled?

Comment: we will leave it as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a simple `for`-loop for this

```
List<DateTime?> dates = new List<DateTime?>()
{
    new DateTime( 2016,10,05,00,00,00),
    null,
    null,
    null,
    new DateTime( 2016, 08, 12 ,07,46,00),
    null,
    null
};


DateTime? latest = null;
for (int i = 0; i < dates.Count; i++)
{
    if (dates[i].HasValue)
    {
        latest = dates[i];
    }
    else
    {
        dates[i] = latest;
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/qqDaMf

Answer (score 0):

Change String class for whatever class u are using.

```
String lastValue = null;

    foreach(var value in ValuesList){
        if(value == null) 
            value = lastValue;
        else
            lastValue = value;
    }
```

Comment: "DateTime lastValue = NULL;" this is not C# and it will not compile unfortunately. DateTime is a non-nullable value type

Comment: Yes, DateTime cannot be null, thats my mistake. Question did not specify value format. So it will work with any nullable. 

Also I edited my answer to use it with strings (for example if it is json input)

Answer (score 0):

```
//input
List<DateTime?> dates = new List<DateTime?> { DateTime.Now, null, DateTime.Parse("2019-10-01"), null };

DateTime? lastPresentDate = dates.FirstOrDefault();
if (lastPresentDate.HasValue) 
{
    dates = dates.Select(d => d.HasValue ? lastPresentDate = d : lastPresentDate).ToList();
}

//output
7/23/2019 7:15:48 AM
7/23/2019 7:15:48 AM
10/1/2019 12:00:00 AM
10/1/2019 12:00:00 AM
```

This will only correct the dates if the first date is present and otherwise leave the list as is.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually have a class (let's say `Product`) with some other properties:

```
DateTime? lastDate = null;
var result = products.Select( 
      p => 
      new { 
          Id = p.Id, 
          CreateDate = (p.CreateDate.HasValue ? (lastDate = p.CreateDate) : lastDate)
          //Other properties..
      }
  );
```

If not and you have just the dates:

```
DateTime? lastDate = null;
var result = dates.Select(d => (d.HasValue ? (lastDate = d.Value) : lastDate));
```

You can add `.ToList()` if you like or not.